# Export InDesign CS5 file for Corel Draw

Tags: adobe-indesign, corel-draw, file-format

I'm sometimes giving small adverts that I created in ID CS5 to a local newspaper. They are building their stuff in Corel. They usually want me to either give them an image (as in jpg) or a pdf file. They don't know what to do with the InDesign file. I've got the feeling that they are actually recreating my stuff in their program, which I don't like at all.

Is there a common file format that both programs can read (or that mine can write, at least)? I don't want them to redo my work, which wastes their time and is error-prone.

Comment: PDF should be your choice if you want to preserve your design. Why hand over the source file at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is the appropriate choice. You can either "export to pdf" directly or use the PDF printer driver (if available) to create the PDF, but either way, ensure:

1) font embedding is enabled;

2) use one of the default presets such as "High Quality Print" or "Press Quality" (don't use "Standard", web, etc)

PDFs are *basically* fixed files which preserve vector information and maintain color spaces, etc.

JPGs are a poor choice because you are fixing the resolution on export rather than having the print provider fixing the resolution at plate time. Also, JPEG compression is lossy by nature. Both of these properties are detrimental to set type.

Comment: I'm already giving them PDF, but I was not aware that they could actually open it and drop it in.

Comment: If you are not embedding the fonts, they may have to rebuild it or substitute. Of course, they might be rebuilding it anyway. I have had to alter client submitted materials on very rare occasions when they simply can't don't and won't submit something to the proper specs.

Comment: I would love to submit it correctly, if only they'd give me all the specs. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

JPG and PDF can be read by both programs. Neither of those file types are editable, it sounds like they are just taking the jpg or pdf and dropping it into their layout in Corel. If you gave them the InDesign file, then they could edit or make alterations to your work.

Comment: At the moment it does not look like they are just dropping it in. They never provide clear information about the size of the advert. And it always looks like they are rebuilding it rather than just dropping it in. The font-size or align might change, or they might alter the colors (which could be due to print). But PDF it already is.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct option available to Import Indesign to CorelDraw, but there is a workaround, Export the Indesign files as a High Quality Print PDF or each of pages as PNG min 600dpi, then import the PNG in CorelDraw and set for print.

This works for me well, I tried importing PDF to CorelDraw, converted text as fonts/curves as graphics but found it consuming.

For publishing, Indesign works really well.